# SQLite exception unable to convert BLOB to string

Tags: android, string, sqlite, blob

In my android project I fetch one problem during retrieving data from data base.
In this I try to get String value from DB like URL but when this code execute then I get this error
**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string**
And only URL colomn give me this error not any other string colomn.

I didn't get where I am wrong. So friend please give me suggestion how I can resolve this problem. Here I also print my LogCat.

Thank You.

```
08-22 20:08:12.290: WARN/System.err(10844): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.catLog.ProductsDetailsHomeTab.getProductDeatilsFromDB(ProductsDetailsHomeTab.java:337)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.catLog.ProductsDetailsHomeTab.setFlipperChild1(ProductsDetailsHomeTab.java:201)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.catLog.Widget.ViewFlipper_ProductDetails.onRightToLeftSwipe(ViewFlipper_ProductDetails.java:68)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.catLog.Widget.ViewFlipper_ProductDetails.onTouchEvent(ViewFlipper_ProductDetails.java:131)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1676)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1112)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1660)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1676)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1112)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1660)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1676)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1112)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1660)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-22 20:08:12.300: WARN/System.err(10844):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the getBlob() function instead of the getString() function will solve the problem. Be careful though since the getBlob() function returns a value of type byte[]. To convert this to a string you have to do something like:

```
String words = "";
try {
     words = new String(words_blob, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method `getBlob(int)`, not `getString(int)`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getBlob(int)

Answer (score 0):

[How to convert BLOB to string?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq250/)

> Direct conversion is not possible without using some UDF, but you can
> extract text using SUBSTRING function:

What is the datatype of the column you are getting the error on (from what you say I think this is the URL column)? Sounds like it is of type BLOB which is a representation of an image but not a string

Comment: Hi CodeBlend , thanks for reply. Here I want to clear that URL is my String column in DB and which is image URL. And to store image I use other Blob column. But my problem is for getting String column value  & I getString like cursorForRecord.getString(cursorForRecord.getColumnIndex("image_url")  And this exception is occur only for URL column not other String column, So please tell me how I am wrong?

Comment: Hi friends , Now I have no any error it resolve automatically without any modification. I don't what happens but now I have no any error. Thanks for being with me.

Comment: Did i help in any way if so mark me as the answer, if not I don't know if you can just close the question?

Comment: I got the same problem. @AmolWadekar can you share how you solve this problem?